# Shinyalert responsiveness issue

Tags: r, shiny, alert

In my code I have a shiny alert set up for deleting an item, but in order for it to work user needs to click the button twice as the first response is always FALSE. I assume its because FALSE is initial value, and the function outputs value and than changes it to the new response. Is there a way to fix it?

Dummy code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyalert(),  # Set up shinyalert
    actionButton("btn", "Delete")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    global <- reactiveValues(response = FALSE)

    observeEvent(input$btn, {
      shinyalert(
        title = "Are you sure you want to delete this file?",
        callbackR = function(x) {
          global$response <- x
        },
        text = "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        type = "warning",
        showCancelButton = TRUE,
        confirmButtonCol = '#DD6B55',
        confirmButtonText = 'Yes, delete it!'
      )
      print(global$response)
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Package `shinyalert` was developed way after the original was put forward https://github.com/timelyportfolio/sweetalertR, I suggest you use that one instead as I had no issues with it so far

Comment: @PorkChop, how do I get a response back from sweetalert?

Comment: Are you sure there's a problem? If you put `observe({ print(global$response) })` below your `observeEvent`, you will see that `global$response` is `TRUE` whenever you click the "Yes" button.